# Name is not saved when partially completing Developer Story

Tags: bug, developer-story

On my developer story, I was completing my general info. I captured the fields
Name, Preferred Technologies, and Job search status and clicked on Continue.

I chose not to complete the next page and left the page, later I returned to the Developer Page and the Name field is empty so I tried again to complete that field but the result is the same. Is this behavior by design or is it a bug?